# Can't connect to SQL Server from my VS Code extension (node.js)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing VS Code extension and want to get some data from SQL Server database. I've tried many different examples but non of them are working for me.

```
        const Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

        const config = {
            user: 'ssrs', // tried userName, username
            password: 'ssrs', 
            server: 'localhost',
            options: {
                database: 'imdb' 
            }
          }

          const connection = new Connection(config);
          connection.on('connect', function(err: string) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log('Connected');
            }
          });
```

OR

```
        await sql.connect('mssql://ssrs:ssrs@localhost/imdb')
        const result = await sql.query`select 1 as one`
        console.dir(result)
```

OR

```
    const sql = require("mssql");
    const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
        database: "imdb",
        server: "localhost",
        driver: "msnodesqlv8",
        userName: "ssrs",
        password: "ssrs"
    });

    conn.connect().then(() => {
        console.log('Connected');
    });
```

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.

[image]

Connecting via `sqlcmd`:

[image]

The port is also open (1433) as I can telnet to it.

Messages from SQL Server log:

> Date      2019-05-08 11:19:02 AM Log      SQL Server (Current - 2019-05-05
>   2:53:00 PM)
>
> Source        Logon
>
> Message Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using
>   SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated
>   authentication only. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]
>
> Date      2019-05-08 11:19:02 AM Log      SQL Server (Current - 2019-05-05
>   2:53:00 PM)
>
> Source        Logon
>
> Message Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58.

Trying to connect with Powershell:

```
  PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "select CURRENT_USER, USER_NAME()" -ServerInstance "localhost" -username "ssrs" -password "ssrs" -Database 'imdb'

Column1 Column2
------- -------
ssrs    ssrs
```

Comment: can you connect via ODBC (testing ODBC connection utility) or some native way like SQL Server Management studio from the machine you are using to connect from?

Comment: yes, I can do that with any other tool for example SSMS using "SQL Server Authentication". I'm not sure what driver does it use.

Comment: Ok.  If you use `sqlcmd` utility to connect does it work? (e.g. `sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P passwd -Q "select @@VERSION"` query returns the version?)  Does the log show anything after you try to connect via the scripts?

Comment: modified the question. I can connect with SQLCMD. Sql Server logs give the same error message (Login failed for user '.')

Comment: Is there an `ERROR STATE`? (Usually as `State: <integer>`) in the logs

Comment: I do not know about the state, but as error message is the same in the SQL Server and application, so I believe that it is early for that, it just can't connect as the user is  not passed for some reason, or something like that.

Comment: Well you have to check the SQL Server logs and see if there is a message like this `2019-02-27 10:02:00.34 Logon     Error: 19342, Severity: 14, State: 8.` in the SQL Server logs.  Then you can match the state of the error log to an actual error happening. (My example error would mean: `8 -  Password mismatch`)

Comment: I'll create an answer.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Have you found a solution to your problem? Any news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in your screenshot, you're able to connect via SQLCMD utility. This means there's no issue with the user or the authentication mode in SQL Server.
The error message is however **misleading** and other users already experienced this [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f8ecd3ce-4fbf-43ea-8360-3172f7ae6973/incorrect-error-details-error-18456-severity-14-state-58-with-sql-server-2008-r2?forum=sqlsecurity).

I'm no expert of node.js but I'd recommend you to better understand how the `mssql` plugin and `Connection` object work. I think that some missing setting in your configuration is making the connection attempt fail.

For example, this code you posted is wrong (**userName** is not valid):

```
const sql = require("mssql");
const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    database: "imdb",
    server: "localhost",
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    userName: "ssrs",
    password: "ssrs"
});

conn.connect().then(() => {
    console.log('Connected');
});
```

It should be:

```
const sql = require("mssql");
const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    database: "imdb",
    server: "localhost",
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    user: "ssrs",
    password: "ssrs"
});

conn.connect().then(() => {
    console.log('Connected');
});
```

Comment: It's just started to work. Most probably I've tried this "user" before I've enabled the right type of authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't connect is written in the log:

> Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is
>   configured for Integrated authentication only.

You have to change the [*authentication mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017) (which you already did according to the screenshot posted) and **restart** the SQL Server service with Agent.  Did you restart the service after changing the mode?

Comment: I did once again. I believe that I wouldn't be able to connect to it with SQLCMD if it wouldn't be enabled and re-started

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Did it work for you?  Well `SQLCMD` is a SQL Server utility it probably has some fallback, hard to say when you do not have the source code.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev hmm, is the setting really changed?  Could you check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer` node `LoginMode` (on the SQL Server machine) what is the value there?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Ok, then it should be fine.  Then the problem is probably somewhere in you node.js API.   I would first thest if Tedious examples (Tedious is a pure-Javascript implementation of the TDS protocol, which is used to interact with instances of Microsoft's SQL Server) work for you - https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/tree/master/examples.  The TDS(Tabular Data Stream Protocol)  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b46a581a-39de-4745-b076-ec4dbb7d13ec